# Open Maps app showing sites near a lat-lon?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Is possible to open Google Maps (Android app or web site) displaying the sites near to a location?

I'm asking for a intent to open googlemaps app to display the sites near a location, not the request to get the sites from Google, that forces my app to procees and display by my self.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by sites??

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and here is the backend api for that

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
                                "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                        sb.append("location=" + mLatitude + "," + mLongitude);
                        sb.append("&radius=5000");
                        sb.append("&types=" + type);
                        sb.append("&sensor=true");
                        sb.append("YOUR API KEY");
```

Comment: Sorry, but this ask Google for a XML/json with the sites near a location. I like to open maps app showing a map with this data.

Answer (score 0):

@Hulk you are partially correct. You call is necessary to show pins near to the location he needs. This code goes in to onMapReady(GoogleMap map) function

```
    LatLng myLatLong = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    // To make you map show the location you need, use moveCamera
    // 13 is the zoom level on the maps
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLatLong, 13));

    //List of all the nearby places from the previous call
    List<Place> nearbyPlaces = getNearbyPlaces(); 

    //Iterate through the nearbyPlaces to add them to the map
    for (Place placeToShow : nearbyPlaces)
         map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title(place.getName())
            .snippet(place.getDescription())
            .position(place.getLatLng()));
```

Also getNearbyPlaces is the call that @Hulk provided

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
                                "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                        sb.append("location=" + mLatitude + "," + mLongitude);
                        sb.append("&radius=5000");
                        sb.append("&types=" + type);
                        sb.append("&sensor=true");
                        sb.append("YOUR API KEY");
```

and the response can be converted to Place Objects.

Place Model a.k.a Place.java

```
Public class Place {
     private String name;
     private String description;
     private LatLng latLng;
 //Also write getters and setters
}
```

Refer to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: @The Matrix if this answer worked for you, could you upvote and accept this answer pls.